# cordova (javascript) file.moveTo wait until finished

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-io, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova (phonegap) to build an Android/iOS App
The App has to cache data. It receives a JSON file from a Server which is then processed (data displayed as HTML).

My problem is in this code:

```
function moveExercisesJSON(){
    console.log("moving exercises json");
    var fail = function(err) { console.log(err) }
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSave, function(file){
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store, function(store){
            file.moveTo(store, "exercises.json");
            console.log("done moving");
            displayExerciseList();
        },fail);
    },fail);
}
```

The JSON file (exercises.json) is downloaded to a downloads-folder, then this function is opened.
The file is moved via file.moveTo. Then displayExerciseList() is opened (which processes/displays the data in the json file).

However, it seems displayExerciseList() is called before file.moveTo is done.
Therefor I am always one version behind when first opened (since the new version has not yet been moved from the downloads-folder)

How can I wait for .moveTo to finish before calling displayExerciseList()
A timer doesn't seem to be a solution since I have to do the same for movie-files (which differ a lot in size).

Comment: I am using a very similar code but it does not appear to be working on iOS using Cordova 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function moveExercisesJSON(){
    console.log("moving exercises json");
    var fail = function(err) { console.log(err) }
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSave, function(file){
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store, function(store){
            file.moveTo(store, "exercises.json",function(){
                console.log("done moving");
                displayExerciseList();
            },function(){
                console.log("error moving");
            });
        },fail);
    },fail);
}
```

The moveTo function has optional parameters for success and error callbacks.

For more details, you can check [this page about HTML5 file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) (on which is based the Cordova File plugin)

Comment: Have you tried this on iOS using Cordova 3.7? the file is not moved but the success callback is called regardless